# ADA - pre and post conditions not working?

Tags: function, procedure, ada, preconditions, post-conditions

I am trying to learn on my own pre and post conditions in ada.

Comment: Definitely worth mentioning your OS, compiler version, and whether it's FSF or Adacore (if Gnat).Obviously compilers pre-dating Ada-2012 won't support this.

Comment: I am using jdoodle online compiler is this a problem ?

Comment: I restored the content of the question. Vandalizing it reduces its value to others.

Comment: "the values of A and B are modifified by the pre/post-condition" - this would be an **incredibly bad idea** even if it was spelt right. (a) you should **never** put code that affects the result in the pre/post condition, as you have seen, (b) it makes it very hard indeed to understand what’s going on, life’s hard enough already

Comment: Currently the question is "I am trying to learn on my own pre and post conditions in ada." seems like a lot is missing and rather useless. Is this normal ? (ongoing moderation ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using GNAT (which looks like it's the default for jdoodle), you need to enable assertions. Add `-gnata` as a command line parameter.

EDIT:
I don't know much about jdoodle, but it seems it can't take arguments to the compiler, only when running your program...

Instead, you could add a `pragma Assertion_Policy` to your program, like this:

```
procedure Tp2q4 is
   pragma Assertion_Policy(Check);

   --...
```